# How do I get gtag to send events automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I am trying to add Google Analytics to our website using the gtag API.
Most of the events I am interested in happen in our PHP code, so I collect them in the session and inject them into the next page that renders. This allows me to handle eg. a login followed by a redirect to the home page.

However, when I try and load the page, none of the injected events are triggered.
I know the system works as I can bind a 'gtag' call to a button's onClick event and it works when I click it, but the automatic ones don't.

Here is an example file: `test.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Analytics</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }

    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');

    // First attempt: Added to the datalayer with the rest of the config.
    gtag('event', 'test-event-1');

    // Second attempt: Added once everything has finished loading.
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        gtag('event', 'test-event-2');
    })
</script>

<div class="container">
    <h1>This is a test</h1>
    <p>Click to trigger another event.</p>
    <!-- Successful attempt: Event is triggered when run from a button event handler. -->
    <button type="button"
            onclick="gtag('event', 'test-event-3')">
        Send Event
    </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this page with Firefox's Network tab running and click the button, I can see the following URLs sent:

```
GET "http://testapp.localhost:9009/analytics-test.html",
GET "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX",
GET "http://testapp.localhost:9009/favicon.ico",
POST "https://region1.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-XXXXXXXXXX&gtm=2oeav0&_p=22328352&cid=1447481123.1666024506&ul=en-us&sr=1920x1080&_s=2&sid=1667482491&sct=17&seg=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Ftestapp.localhost%2Fanalytics-test.html&dt=Test%20Analytics&en=user_engagement&_et=4840",
POST "https://region1.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-XXXXXXXXXX&gtm=2oeb20&_p=1344830813&cid=1447481123.1666024506&ul=en-us&sr=1920x1080&sid=1667482491&sct=17&seg=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Ftestapp.localhost%2Fanalytics-test.html&dt=Test%20Analytics&_s=1",
POST "https://region1.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-XXXXXXXXXX&gtm=2oeb20&_p=1344830813&cid=1447481123.1666024506&ul=en-us&sr=1920x1080&_s=2&sid=1667482491&sct=17&seg=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Ftestapp.localhost%2Fanalytics-test.html&dt=Test%20Analytics&en=test-event-3&_ee=1&_et=14263",
```

The 'en' is the event name, so you can see that only 'test-event-3' is sent to Google.
Please can you let me know how to change the code so that 'test-event-1' and 'test-event-2' are sent to Google as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, many issues, but the most likely issue here is that your config happens before the library is loaded. Move your gtag config to the window load. Gtag may not be smart enough to retroactively inspect the dataLayer.

Another issue here is that you seem to be looking at the network tab. There's a way easier way to debug analytics. I suggest trying the [Adswerve debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adswerve-datalayer-inspec/kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom) extension. It shows your events in a much easier to look at presentation right in the console:

[image]

Good. Another issue here is that you're editing a php file. This kind of implementation is being frowned upon by the industry. There are many problems around implementing tracking in backend files. Implementing it in the template files would be a bit better, but still quite a poor design.

The proper implementation would be using [GTM](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6102821?hl=en). GTM would handle retroactive datalayer pushes better, but you would also likely not need them with GTM. GTM is basically a script that is able to intelligently load other scripts whenever is required and translate business-like logic set via its UI to code. So with GTM, you just load it on every page and the rest of the tracking is done in its interface.

While doing gtag calls manually is a way to implement tracking, it's like making a site with no web-server, just quickly deploying your own backend network listeners that would spew html in response. A very odd and niche choice not making sense in vast majority of cases. Don't expect this kind of tracking to live long, to be appreciated, to be scalable or manageable or even to be very useful. Not a great legacy either.

Comment: Thanks for recommending Adswerve debugger. This showed me that the events were getting through, they just weren't visible on the Network Manager display.

Comment: Regarding your other comments, thanks for the advice.  The site is actually a Symfony PHP site; I just edited a PHP file manually to show the problem. I'll look into GTM. 

I'll use regular pageview tracking where possible, but there are places where I need custom events, eg. if the user is redirected back to the account page after a login attempt and I need to know if the login was successful or not.